# Prevent google drive from changing names of hidden files prefixed with '.'

Tags: google-drive

I upload a directory to Google drive, e.g. `somedir` containing hidden files, `.gitignore` and `.ignoreme`.  When I download it and unpack the zip file, the files have been renamed to `_gitignore` and `_ignoreme`.  This is pretty annoying.  Is there a way for this to not happen?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle).